# Sentence Structure in "Wir wollen uns nun Vokabeln zu darstellender Kunst ansehen."

Tags: translation

I have the following sentence in my textbook:

> Wir wollen uns nun Vokabeln zu darstellender Kunst ansehen.

As the subject is "Wir", I can say the conjugation is going to be the same as the infinitive, hence the verb "wollen" here is used, which I know means "to want / wish / desire" etc.

"nun" means "now" and "Vokabeln" means vocabulary.

Now, I thought

> zu darstellender Kunst ansehen

was an infinite clause:

i.e. to see performing arts.

But if I try to put the sentence together, what I seem to get is:

> We want to now Vocabulary to see performing arts.

Is this sentence wrong? Is the verb "lernen" missing here?

Comment: Think of "Vokabeln zu darstellender Kunst" as a single entity

Answer (score 3):

The piece

> … zu darstellender Kunst ansehen …

can't be an infinitive clause. Don't let the *zu* fool you. It has to precede the infinitive or must be built in for separable verbs. If the *zu* precedes something else than an infinitive, it's a preposition. The meaning of the piece is:

> … zu darstellender Kunst …

*… about performing arts …*

and *ansehen* is the infinitive belonging to the modal *wollen*.

Comment: Should it be noted that *zu* is a suboptimal choice here? It could be omitted, without a change of meaning. It could be "der darstellenden Kunst", or "für" or "von"

Comment: @Janka No. "Zu" can't be omitted without changing the meaning. It defines the relationship between the vocabularies and the art. `Wir wollen uns nun Vokabeln darstellender Kunst ansehen` would refere to vocabularies of performing art (like movements that have vocabular-like meanings).

Comment: It seems you answered a different question.

Answer (score 3):

The sentence is correct, nothing is missing here.

Let's build the sentence beginning with this minimal sentence:

> Wir sehen uns etwas an.
>   We look at something.

The verb *»ansehen«* is a separable verb, and therefore it is split into *»sehen«* and *»an«* here.

Add a modal verb:

> Wir **wollen** uns etwas ansehen.
>   We **want to** look at something.

Now the modal word occupies position 2, so the parts of *»ansehen«* are joined together and stand on the last position.

When do want to do it?

> Wir wollen uns **nun** etwas ansehen.
>   We **now** want to look at something.

But *»etwas«* (*something*) is rather wishy-washy. We want to make it more concrete:

> Wir wollen uns nun **Vokabeln** ansehen.
>   We now want to look at **vocabulary**.

This still is too unspecified. Let's make it even more concrete:

> Wir wollen uns nun Vokabeln **zu darstellender Kunst** ansehen.
>   We now want to look at vocabulary **about performing Arts**.

Clear now?

Answer (score 0):

Wir wollen ansehen -> we want to look at ...

Now we want to look at the vocabulary of ...

darstellende Kunst = performing (dramatic) art

darstellender = genitiv of adjectiv

Darsteller = acter

darstellen = verb

darstellend = partizip present wird zu adjektiv

darstellender = adjektiviertes Verb im Genitiv

Now you can put together your sentence.